# Breeze NH - FK on base class save error

Tags: breeze

Using breeze.webapi.nh (1.4.7) I have a simple TPT/TPH (tried both) (BasePayment, CreditcardPayment) queries on the CredticardPayment object works just fine and I get the data from the base and derived class.

When trying to save the entity and the base class contains FK I get this error: (if the FK are moved to the derived class the save works and everything is fine)

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Breeze.WebApi.NH.NHRelationshipFixer.GetRelatedEntity(String propName, IType propType, EntityInfo entityInfo, IClassMetadata meta, Boolean canUseSession)
   at Breeze.WebApi.NH.NHRelationshipFixer.FixupRelationship(String propName, IType propType, EntityInfo entityInfo, IClassMetadata meta, Boolean canUseSession)
   at Breeze.WebApi.NH.NHRelationshipFixer.FixupRelationships(EntityInfo entityInfo, IClassMetadata meta, Boolean canUseSession)
   at Breeze.WebApi.NH.NHRelationshipFixer.FixupRelationships(Boolean canUseSession)
   at Breeze.WebApi.NH.NHContext.ProcessSaves(Dictionary`2 saveMap)
   at Breeze.WebApi.NH.NHContext.SaveChangesCore(SaveWorkState saveWorkState)
   at Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider.OpenAndSave(SaveWorkState saveWorkState)
   at Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle, TransactionSettings transactionSettings)
   at YTourWeb.Controllers.BreezeApiController.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) in c:\Yayasoft\YTour\YTour\YTourWeb\Controllers\BreezeApiController.cs:line 46
```

Any ideas?

save bundle:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "Id": 5,
      "TotalAmount": 20,
      "CurrencyId": 1,
      "CurrencyRate": 3.5,
      "CreateDate": "2014-01-05T09:54:51Z",
      "PaymentDate": null,
      "OrderId": 316,
      "NumberOfPayments": 0,
      "Token": null,
      "ConfirmationCode": null,
      "HolderFirstName": null,
      "HolderLastName": null,
      "HolderIdNumber": null,
      "LastFourDigits": null,
      "ExpireDate": null,
      "Remarks": null,
      "CardType": "Visa",
      "PaymentType": "Regular",
      "Status": "None",
      "ErrorCode": 0,
      "ChargeDate": null,
      "CVV": null,
      "ClearingService": "NotSet",
      "entityAspect": {
        "entityTypeName": "CreditcardPayment:#BL.Orders",
        "defaultResourceName": "CreditcardPayments",
        "entityState": "Modified",
        "originalValuesMap": {
          "TotalAmount": 10
        },
        "autoGeneratedKey": {
          "propertyName": "Id",
          "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "saveOptions": {}
}
```

metadata:

```
{
      "shortName": "CreditcardPayment",
      "namespace": "BL.Orders",
      "baseTypeName": "BasePayment:#BL.Orders",
      "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
      "defaultResourceName": "CreditcardPayments",
      "dataProperties": [
        {
          "nameOnServer": "NumberOfPayments",
          "dataType": "Int32",
          "isNullable": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "name": "int32"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "Token",
          "dataType": "String",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "ConfirmationCode",
          "dataType": "String",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "HolderFirstName",
          "dataType": "String",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "HolderLastName",
          "dataType": "String",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "HolderIdNumber",
          "dataType": "String",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "LastFourDigits",
          "dataType": "String",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "ExpireDate",
          "dataType": "DateTime",
          "isNullable": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "name": "date"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "Remarks",
          "dataType": "String",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "CardType",
          "dataType": "NHibernate.Type.EnumType`1[[BL.Orders.CreditcardPayment+CreditCardTypes, BL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], NHibernate",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "PaymentType",
          "dataType": "NHibernate.Type.EnumType`1[[BL.Orders.CreditcardPayment+CreditCardPaymentTypes, BL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], NHibernate",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "Status",
          "dataType": "NHibernate.Type.EnumType`1[[BL.Orders.CreditcardPayment+CreditCardStatus, BL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], NHibernate",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "ErrorCode",
          "dataType": "Int32",
          "isNullable": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "name": "int32"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "ChargeDate",
          "dataType": "DateTime",
          "isNullable": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "name": "date"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "CVV",
          "dataType": "String",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "ClearingService",
          "dataType": "NHibernate.Type.EnumType`1[[BL.Orders.CreditcardPayment+CreditClearingServices, BL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], NHibernate",
          "isNullable": true
        }
      ],
      "navigationProperties": []
    },
    {
      "shortName": "BasePayment",
      "namespace": "BL.Orders",
      "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
      "defaultResourceName": "BasePayments",
      "dataProperties": [
        {
          "nameOnServer": "Id",
          "dataType": "Int32",
          "isNullable": false,
          "isPartOfKey": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "name": "required"
            },
            {
              "name": "int32"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "TotalAmount",
          "dataType": "Double",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "CurrencyId",
          "dataType": "Int32",
          "isNullable": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "name": "int32"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "CurrencyRate",
          "dataType": "Double",
          "isNullable": true
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "CreateDate",
          "dataType": "DateTime",
          "isNullable": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "name": "date"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "PaymentDate",
          "dataType": "DateTime",
          "isNullable": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "name": "date"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "OrderId",
          "dataType": "Int32",
          "isNullable": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "name": "int32"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "navigationProperties": [
        {
          "nameOnServer": "Currency",
          "entityTypeName": "Currency:#BL",
          "isScalar": true,
          "associationName": "AN_BasePayment_Currency",
          "foreignKeyNamesOnServer": [
            "CurrencyId"
          ]
        },
        {
          "nameOnServer": "Order",
          "entityTypeName": "Order:#BL.Orders",
          "isScalar": true,
          "associationName": "AN_BasePayment_Order",
          "foreignKeyNamesOnServer": [
            "OrderId"
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a bug.  Sorry about that.  It's fixed in version 1.4.8, which should be released tomorrow.

Comment: thanks i also know after some research what was the problem and i applied a fix for it (had to rebuild). i wonder if my fix would be the same as the fix you will apply in 1.4.8